# How to adding a flags config just for specific files in Premake?

Tags: premake

I want to add flags "XXX" just only for some specific files

I could end up using the filter but I must creat each filter for each file, it is not comfortable. The reason I must separate each filter for each file is that I can't find the way to define all files into just one filter (can't use *)

```
filter { "files:../src/A.cpp"} 
    flags "XXX"
filter { "files:../utils/B.cpp"}
    flags "XXX"
```

Do you know how to list all files into one filter, or another way to adding flags XXX into each specific file?

Thank in advice!

Answer (score 0):

That is the right way to do it, put per-file settings are sort of hit or miss right now. You'll have the best luck with Visual Studio, not sure if Gmake supports them at all (yet).